# How to check if a timestamp is an hour old?

Tags: php, api, twitter, timestamp

I am building a caching system to store Twitter API tweets as to avoid violating the hourly call limit.

I am storing the tweets in a database with a timestamp and then checking in PHP to see if the timestamp is an hour old, if so then I call the API again. At the moment I can't seem to get it working. Here is what I curently have (which I admit is most probably wrong!)

```
 if($results->tweet_date <= strtotime('-1 hours')) {
 //do api call
 } else {
 //call tweets from database
 }
```

This doesn't seem to be working though. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: What is `$results->tweet_date` like?

Comment: How did you determine whether it works or not? Did you dump the two numbers and compared them manually?

Comment: When I print out the two numbers this is what I get.. <!--2012-09-13 11:07:49--><!--1347527334-->

Comment: Don't worry, I haved fixed it now. Needed to strtotime on the timestamp. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the timestamp minus 3600?

```
if($results->tweet_date <= time() - 3600) {
//do api call
} else {
//call tweets from database
}
```

EDIT: If you want to use `strtotime`, you can use `strtotime('-1 hour')` to calculate the time (mind the hour instead of hours).

Comment: It still seems to be executing through the 'if' part of the statement. I don't have the operator the wring way round? (<= instead of >=)?

Comment: The if looks good. Maybe the tweet_date is not in the correct format?