# javascript unix timestamp older than x

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I need to clarify an assumpton I have made with unix timestamps before I go and make something that messes my application flow, I can't visualise the numbers at all I don't wan't to do the opposite..

There is a question here about this with php but not one that I can find with javascript

[How to check if a timestamp is an hour old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403189/how-to-check-if-a-timestamp-is-an-hour-old)

My array of arrays will be built by my application like this

```
var list=[
['name0',1424300986716,1424301040055,1424301049633],
['name1',1424300998116,1424301019372,1424301059418],
['name2',1424301009043,1424301030315,1424301059418]
//...
];
```

I would like to determin if the second column of timestamps has one which is over 24 hours <del>long</del> old (none of these are I just made them now), I need it to get the first one that it comes across not the oldest and return the array index

if I run this test I get more confused as I am in italy I think some thing is screewy with the timezones or clock or I have the wrong idea

```
var now=(+new Date());

var back24hrs=new Date((now-86400));

console.log(now,back24hrs);

// 1424303535659 Thu Feb 19 2015 00:50:49 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

It's thursday now that is now not back 24 hrs! I can't see how I am wrong..

basicly my assumption is (current time - 24hrs) I think that part is correct but also less than or greater than the saved time?

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
function olderthan24hrs(column){
    var hrs24=86400;
    var i=list.length;
    while(i--){
        if((+new Date()-hrs24)>list[i][column]){break;}
        }
    return i;
    }

var choice=olderthan24hrs(2);
```

But I'm really not sure if that would be at all correct

Comment: _“I would like to determin if the second column of timestamps has one which is over 24 hours long”_ – that doesn’t make sense, how can a single timestamp be “over 24 hours long”? (Well, technically _all_ unix timestamps for dates more than one day after epoch would be “more than 24 hours long”, but that would be a weird way of locking at it.)

Comment: And where you are going wrong with subtracting your value of `86400` is of course the fact that JavaScript’s `Date` object operates with _milliseconds_, not seconds … so you’re subtracting a mere 84.6 _seconds_ from the current timestamp there, and not “a whole day’s worth of seconds” as you think.

Comment: LOL!! smashed it... I don't understand what you mean in your first comment. say for example if my app saved a time stamp a day and a half ago in that list that one would be *'one which is over 24 hours long'* surely

Comment: Well it would be more precise to call that more than 24 hours _ago_, not “long”.

Comment: I have updated, thank you. for making things clear. If you can make an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript’s `Date` object operates with milliseconds, not seconds.

So with `86400` you’re subtracting a mere `84.6` *seconds* from the current timestamp, and not “a whole day’s worth of seconds” as you think. You need to multiply that value by a thousand.

(And subtracting 86400 seconds doesn’t mean exactly one day all the time, since there are two days in the year that are one hour longer resp. shorter, at least in any country that has daylight saving time. Whether or not that is relevant for your application, you must decide yourself.)

Comment: So the safest bet would be 25hrs which really is (3600*1000)*25

Comment: No, the safest bet would be to use `setDate`, which makes the Date object take that into account on it’s own.

Comment: It’s as simple as `var d=new Date; d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);` – and you have “this time yesterday”. (And it takes care of all “boundaries”, like from Feb 1st to Jan 31st etc. automatically.)

Comment: BTW, daylight saving is observed based on various types of administrative areas other than countries, such as states, regions, counties and so on.

Comment: @CBroe—it depends on whether the OP wants "same time yesterday" or 24 elapsed hours earlier. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer, but just to clarify: UNIX and JavaScript (ECMAScript) use the same epoch for time values, however UNIX time values are seconds and javascript time values are in milliseconds. There are 8.64e7 milliseconds in 24 hours.

If you want to see if the time is greater than 24 elapsed hours ago, set the comparison value by subtracting 24 hours worth of seconds form the time value in seconds:

```
// Current time value in seconds
var then = (Date.now()/1000 | 0) - 8.64e4;
```

However, the time that this relates to on the previous day will be +/- 1 hour when it crosses a daylight saving boundary.

If you want to compare to the same time yesterday (so 23 or 25 hours over the daylight saving boundary), use a date object and subtract a day to create the comparison value:

```
var now = new Date();
var then = +(now.setDate(now.getDate() - 1))/1000 | 0;
```

Then do the comparison (same for both):

```
if (list[i][column] < then) {
  // value is prior to comparison time
}
```

Note that storing the *then* value is much more efficient than calculating it on each iteration.

Your while loop starts:

```
while(i--){
```

So this is a decrementing loop so you'll get the last value over 24 hours old, not the first. To get the first:

```
for (var i=0, iLen=list.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if ((list[i][column] < then) {
      return i;
    }
}
```

that way if there is no time more before the comparison time, the function returns undefined. In the OP, it will return -1 if a suitable time isn't found.